# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

### The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

In this election there is only one open moderator position.

Please visit the [official election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14) for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [moderator-election](/questions/tagged/moderator-election).

Comment: @Machavity The election page (there are multiple tabs) & the election FAQ do not say how to nominate yourself. I haven't found how searching. Maybe there's a button for those who meet minimum qualifications (I don't) but that still leaves others uninformed. Also, when there were no nominations it was not clear where the nomination posts would appear. Maybe on that page--but again, not clear when there are none & no mention of it to search for if an election isn't on.

Comment: @philipxy Might be worth a separate Meta post to document it. The link to nominate yourself is at the bottom of the election page itself. What's odd about it is it's got to have your user ID at the end so sharing the link won't help you any.

Comment: @Machavity Like I said no button/link for me. The "nomination" link at page bottom just links back to the page+tab itself, no user specialization. https://stackoverflow.com/election?tab=nomination Yeah, now that I have composed my previous comment, I may compose a question.

Comment: @philipxy I'm jealous. I demand that my user ID is added to the custom code which prevents people from nominating themselves. I've earned it!